Global bound on the minsize of geodesic triangles implies triangles are slim
I have been going over the concept of Gromov Hyperbolic space from the book "Group Theory from a  Geometric Viewpoint " by E.Ghys, A Haefliger , A Verjovsky.
There is a proposition at the beginning of the first chapter, regarding the equivalence of definition of  a $\delta-$ Hyperbolic space.
I have question in a subpart of that proposition. (Page 16)
Definition  1 (Slim triangles) Given any three points $x,y,z$ in a geodesic metric space $X$ , we say that a triangle $xyz$ of geodesics joining these points is $\delta -$ slim if if for any $w\in [xy]$ we have that $min \{d(w,[xz]),d(w,[yz])\}\le \delta.$ We say that triangles are slim in  $X$ if there is a constant $\delta $ such that all geodesic triangles in $X$ are $\delta-$slim.
Definition 2 (Minsize)Let $xyz$ be a geodesic triangle and let $x',y',z'$ be points on $xyz(x'$ on the side opposite vertex $x$ etc ). Define the minsize of the triangle to be
$minsize (xyz)=inf $ diam$\{x',y',z'\}$ infimum is taken over all $\{x',y',z'\}$.
Question: Show that ,  For a geodesic metric space $X$ if there is a global bound on the minsize of geodesic triangles then Triangles are slim.
Proof(Page 17): Let $x',y',z'$ be points on $[yz],[xz],[xy]$ such that diam$\{x',y',z'\}\le\delta.$ This reduces the problem to studying three geodesic triangles each with base $\le\delta.$
Suppose that there is a point $t\in [xz']$ such that $d(t,[xy'])>2\delta .$ Let $u$ be the point in $[z't]$ nearest to $t$ such that $d(u,u')=2\delta $ for some point $u'\in[xy']$. Now  consider the geodesic triangle $uúx.$ The bound on the minsize of triangles implies that there are points $a,b,c$ on the three sides of $uúx$ such that diam$\{a,b,c\}\le \delta. $ The point $a$ on $[xu]$
does not lie in $[tu] $by supposition,  and $d(u,a)\le 3\delta ,$ so $d(t,ù)\le 3\delta $ or $d(t,c)\le 3 \delta. $
My doubts:1)why we can get such an $u'$ such that $d(u,u')=2\delta? $
2)Why $a$ doesn't lie in $[tu]$?
3) Why$d(u,a)<3\delta $?
